# How to move the message in the view like success or not success

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

**My controller**

//category retrieving the values from categories

```
$category['categorylist']=$this->usermodel->categorylist();
$data['message']="Product sucessfully inserted";
$this->load->view('admin/products',$category);
```

**My view**

```
<?php
if(isset ($message))
{
    echo $message;
}
?>
```

In the view I also want to display the success message after inserted, but if I keep like

```
$this->load->view('admin/products',$category,$data);
```

then the success message is not displayed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `$message`? Could you explain a bit more your problem?

Comment: $message will print the message as 'Product sucessfully inserted'

Comment: where do you set `$message`?

Comment: $data['message']="Product sucessfully inserted";  In the controller i set the message and that message is passed to the view as $this->load->view('admin/products',$category,$data); If i remove $category the message will work

Comment: I also want the $category also to move to the view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only pass one array to the view, so both `message` and `category` have to be in the same array.

```
$data['category'] = $this->usermodel->categorylist();
$data['message'] = 'Product sucessfully inserted';
$this->load->view('admin/products', $data);
```

With this you can use `$category` and `$message` in the view.

Comment: You are nice myfriend ,u make me to remember my basics